# how to compare date and time in javascript using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to compare updated date and time with current date and time. here i am getting one array of object there inside i have one updated at key . I need to find which object  is near to current date and time and update another key inside that object.

```
     for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++){ 
        if(data[i].updated_at > data[i+1].updated_at ){
          data.is_latest="true"
              }
       }
 // below is my data
  
                              [
                            {
                                "is_latest": "",
                                "created_at": "2021-09-21T21:24:05.000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2021-09-21T17:53:29.000Z"
                            },
                            {
                                "is_latest": "",
                                "created_at": "2021-09-29T21:24:05.000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2021-09-29T17:53:29.000Z"
                            }
                        ]

  // in the above i am getting data here how to find updated_at nearer to current date and time using moment.js
      
                                 [
                            {
                                "is_latest": "",
                                "created_at": "2021-09-21T21:24:05.000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2021-09-21T17:53:29.000Z"
                            },
                            {
                                "is_latest": true,
                                "created_at": "2021-09-29T21:24:05.000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2021-09-29T17:53:29.000Z"
                            }
                        ]
```

how to resolve this using map function

Comment: `I am trying`...are you? Please show your attempt then, and explain where you got stuck / what error you encountered. It's unclear what the problem is. Is your issue specifically how to compare two dates with momentJS, or about the algorithm to process through the array, or what? Please be more specific. Stackoverflow is not a free write-my-code service, but we will _help_ you with _your_ attempt to implement what you need. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you're trying.

Comment: i am new to this.. i have updated please check

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
let today = Date.now();
let latest_index = 0, latest_diff = today - (new Date(data[0].updated_at)).getTime();

for(let i=1;i<data.length; i++){ 
  let updated_date = (new Date(data[i].updated_at)).getTime();

  if (today - updated_date < latest_diff){
    latest_index = i;
    latest_diff = today - updated_date;
  }
     
}
```

Note:

```
(new Date()).getTime;
// This will return you the number of milliseconds elapsed from January 1, 1970 
// if your date is less than that date, the value will be negative
```